# .NET POST to PHP Page

Tags: c#, php, .net, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement a very basic system from my C# .NET application that sends the IP address of the machine to authenticate.php on my web server. The php page will check this IP address against a database and either respond back with "yes" or "no".

It has been a long time since I worked with PHP, and I am a little bit confused. Here is what my .NET function looks like.

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated()
{
    string sData = getPublicIP();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/authenticate.php");
    if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentLength = sData.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // POST the data to the authentication page
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(sData);
        writer.Close();

        // Retrieve response from authentication page
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        if (sResponse == "yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication was Successful.");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication Failed!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So would the POST variable be $_POST['sData']; and how do I respond back to my application with the result?

Comment: I think it is also worth noting that authenticating against IP is extremely dangerous.  One IP could be mapped to potentially thousands of machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the value of `sData` is (say) "10.1.1.1" then you're currently not posting proper form data in the first place. The name of the variable isn't part of the text written by

```
 writer.Write(sData);
```

You need to do something like:

```
 string postData = "ipaddress=" + sData;
```

and then use the `ipaddress` form parameter within your PHP.

Note also that you should be giving the *binary* content length, which may not be the same as the *string* length in characters. Of course it's okay if the string here is entirely ASCII, which I'd expect if it's an IP address... but it's worth bearing in mind for other uses. (Likewise you would normally need to bear in mind any characters which need special encoding.)

Also note that it would be better to use `using` statements for the `StreamWriter`, `HttpResponse` etc, to make sure that everything gets closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for the response and excellent points! Do you mind answering the question about how I actually respond back to the POST request though from the PHP page? I will be happy to mark as answered after that.

Comment: @Brett: I don't know PHP, but I'd expect any good PHP tutorial to handle this. For example, have a look at http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-form.html?page=2 - I would suggest that to make things easier for development, you decouple the PHP part from the .NET part; get the PHP part working using a simple HTML form for testing (to provide the data).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that just using the echo command was the equivalent of a response.

Comment: @Brett Powell: well how do you think your browser works? In a netshell: it sends an HTTP request to the server (to the URL you specified), then receives the response (in this case, the output of the executed PHP script), from which it renders the page you see (again, in case of HTML and friends). You can see the request/response headers using e.g. Firebug for Firefox, or Dragonfly in Opera, and you can view the raw response text by right click on the page -> view source. Google for the HTTP protocol to learn more.