# Cannot see JSON posted from ASP.NET/IIS Application

Tags: php, asp.net, json

I am working with another company to build a customer billing interface to their reporting software. Their system is built using ASP.NET/IIS and my system is built using PHP/Apache. They have an API that sends/receives JSON data over POST using a content-type of application/json; charset=UTF-8

I wrote a wrapper for sending data to them which they receive just fine, and also set up an endpoint for them to send data to which works just fine when I test it with cURL or Chrome's "Postman" extension, but I can't see any data they send me.

Basically my endpoint grabs the raw post data from php://input like this:

```
$pData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$pData = json_decode($pData);
```

As stated before this works great when I use postman, but when they send the request I see no raw data, nothing in $_POST and of course nothing in $_GET. I have even tried $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA which gives me the same result as php://input.

I am logging all requests and can see they are making the request to my endpoint, but there is no content-length given so I can't tell if the data is even making it to me. Is there something I am missing on my end that would cause me to miss the raw data from an ASP.NET application? Or is it safe to assume the issue is on their end?

Thanks

Comment: How do get data that they send? How is the communication between them  and you?

Comment: Their system posts raw JSON data to my endpoint, lets call it file.php, that file reads the contents of php://input - This works when I post raw JSON using the content type application/json. When they send the POST though I see the request but no data.

Comment: Looks like they don't send the right headers? They must be sure to send a POST request with Content Type application/json.

Comment: They are sending the headers. Content-Type application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I suspect the Name data might be missing and this is not allowing $_POST to parse it properly. What do you see in the logs exactly? What is the sample data look like? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248205/net-post-to-php-page

Answer (score 0):

Issue was on their end apparently. index.php was under a couple directories like https://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/index.php - They were posting to https://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2 which apparently didn't work but posting to https://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/ worked fine. Not sure why that was an issue for ASP.NET/IIS and not for PHP/Apache, cURL from a linux terminal, Postman, and http://hurl.it